# Is null in c# value type or reference type

Tags: c#, null

Originally I had this impression that NULL is reference type because it is assigned to references, then encountered this concept called nullable value types, this makes my theory in an awkward situation, so is NULL value type of reference type on earth ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The C# specification is clear on this point: the `null` keyword represent an *expression that has no type*. It is neither reference type nor value type nor pointer type. However that expression is *convertible* to all of those types. There is no requirement that the compiler classify all expressions as having a type, and in fact it does not.

Now you might then ask *at runtime* what is the type of a null reference, what is the type of a null value of nullable value type, and what is the type of a null pointer. The answers are:

- a null reference does not have a type. If you have a box that can hold chocolates it is pointless to ask "what brand of chocolates are in this empty box?"  A missing chocolate does not have a brand; a null reference does not have a type.
- similarly, the type of a null pointer is, again, not anything; null pointer values don't point to anything. If you have a piece of paper that has the address 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue on it, you can ask "what is the colour of the house at this address", and get the answer: white. If you have a blank piece of paper, asking what the colour of the house at that address is doesn't get you any useful answer.
- a null value of a nullable value type is a value of the nullable value type.

Comment: this is exactly the answer I am expecting. sometimes find myself not expressing the question very well, but the question combined with the answer expresses exactly what I am trying to get clear.

Answer (score 9):

`null` isn't a type.

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx):

> The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one that does not refer to any object.

[Nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) are instances of the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) struct which "*Represents a value type that can be assigned null.*"

Answer (score 1):

Neither. `null` is the `default` value for reference types, but it does not have a type itself.

Nullable value types are actually implemented as value types themselves - there are just compiler and library tricks to make them behave as expected when compared to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`null` doesn't have a type by itself in C#, as it was already said here. I think some precise examples showing the implications of this definition are missing from the other answers.

### var something = null;

is invalid

```
string a = null; // valid. Null is implicitely casted to string.
int? b = null; // valid. Null is implicitely casted to Nullable<int>.
var c = "hello" // valid, type of c is infered by the compiler by looking at the right side of the expression.

var d = null; // not valid, compiler can't infer any type from null !
```

The invalid line in the above example will cause the following compilation error :

> Error - CS0815 - Cannot assign  to an implicitly-typed variable

and also :

### Passing null to overloaded methods might require an explicit cast

```
void myMethod(int? myParam) { }
void myMethod(string myParam) { }

void test 
{
    string a = null;
    myMethod(a); // no problem here, a is of type string so 2nd overload will be used.

    myMethod(null); // not valid ! Compiler can't guess which one you want.

    myMethod((string) null); // valid, null is casted to string so 2nd overload is to be used.
}
```

The invalid line in the above example will cause the following compilation error :

> Error - CS0121 - The call is ambiguous between the following methods
>   or properties: 'myMethod(string)' and 'myMethod(int?)'

Answer (score 0):

null does not reference to anything. It is just a type points to nothing. You people usually use it to de-reference an object.

Answer (score -1):

The `null` keyword in C# does represent a null reference, so you can consider it a reference type (although technically it indicates not type).

The C# compiler and extra handling of `null` for use with nullable types.   Nullable value types and value types and can never actually be `null`.   When you assign or compare a Nullable value type to `null` the compiler will replace the code.

For example:

```
int? i;
if (i == null)
    i = 1;
```

Is replaced by the compiler with:

```
int? i;
if (!i.HasVaue)
   i = 1;
```